# Dynamic filter: Creating a dynamic filter using .filter()

Tags: javascript, filter

```js
let users = [
    { id: 11, name: 'Adam', age: 23, group: 'editor' },
    { id: 47, name: 'John', age: 28, group: 'admin' },
    { id: 85, name: 'William', age: 34, group: 'editor' },
    { id: 97, name: 'Oliver', age: 28, group: 'admin' }
  ];

var getFilteredUsers = (array, key, value) => array.filter(x => x[key] === value);
var FilteredUsers = getFilteredUsers(users, "age", 28);
console.log(FilteredUsers);
```

I am trying to create a dynamic filter, based on the `key:value` passed in `getgetFilteredUsers()` will give the corresponding output.

Right now, `getgetFilteredUsers()` is only computing `equals to`. But I want to use this same function to compare all three comparisons i.e equals to, less than and greater than.

Comment: Can you define the interface; or, how you would use it when there is a "less than" symbol ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take functions for comparison and hand over the wanted one or take `equal` comparison as default one.

```js
const
    equal = (a, b) => a === b,
    lt = (a, b) => a < b,
    gt = (a, b) => a > b,
    filter = (array, key, value, cf = equal) => array.filter(x => cf(x[key], value));

var users = [{ id: 11, name: 'Adam', age: 23, group: 'editor' }, { id: 47, name: 'John', age: 28, group: 'admin' }, { id: 85, name: 'William', age: 34, group: 'editor' }, { id: 97, name: 'Oliver', age: 28, group: 'admin' }],
    user28 = filter(users, "age", 28),
    userLT28 = filter(users, "age", 28, lt);

console.log(user28);
console.log(userLT28);
```

Answer (score 5):

An alternative is passing the predicate which will be called by the function `filter`

```js
let users = [{ id: 11, name: 'Adam', age: 23, group: 'editor' },{ id: 47, name: 'John', age: 28, group: 'admin' },{ id: 85, name: 'William', age: 34, group: 'editor' },{ id: 97, name: 'Oliver', age: 28, group: 'admin' }];
let getFilteredUsers = (array, handler) => array.filter(handler);

let  FilteredUsers = getFilteredUsers(users, x => x['age'] === 28);
console.log(FilteredUsers);

FilteredUsers = getFilteredUsers(users, x => x['age'] > 28);
console.log(FilteredUsers);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: What's the benefit to do this instead of passing the predicate directly to `filter()`?

Comment: @Amessihel hiding logic within the function `getFilteredUsers`, and that way it follows a DRY principle.  It doesn't make sense to create a function for doing only that call of `filter`, however, the OP wants to add some more logic inside of the function `getFilteredUsers`.

Comment: I understand the "hiding" concept, but not how the DRY principle applies here. Could you please elaborate? It's like we'll repeat the `getFilteredUsers()` call rather than the `filter` one.

Comment: @Amessihel look at the other answer, see how the condition === string is repeated.  That's not a DRY principle.  Well, it was removed!

Comment: @Ele, Okay I see what you mean: it follows the DRY principle in _its implementation_. I was just saying you won't reduce the repetition of the `filter()` call by replacing it with a `getFilteredUsers()` one. Thank you

Comment: elegant solution. +1 to what @Amessihel said.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an object to hold your operations and index this object to get the right function to apply for that operation:

```js
const users = [
  { id: 11, name: 'Adam', age: 23, group: 'editor' },
  { id: 47, name: 'John', age: 28, group: 'admin' },
  { id: 85, name: 'William', age: 34, group: 'editor' },
  { id: 97, name: 'Oliver', age: 28, group: 'admin' }
];

const filterUsers = (arr, key, value, op = 'eq') => {
  const ops = {
    eq: (x, y) => x === y,
    lt: (x, y) => x < y,
    gt: (x, y) => x > y
  };
  return arr.filter(x => ops[op](x[key], value));
};

console.log(filterUsers(users, 'age', 28));
console.log(filterUsers(users, 'age', 28, 'lt'));
console.log(filterUsers(users, 'age', 28, 'gt'));
```